# Cron on XAMPP (windows)

Tags: php, windows, drupal, cron, xampp

I am developing a site locally using xampp. I would like to configure cron, so the dev environment is the same as the production environment. However, my system is windows vista. Is there any way to do this, or am I forced to accept that my dev and production environments will be forks?

Comment: It is also worth remembering that you can call /cron.php to run the drupal cron on a dev environment.

Comment: useful link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093141/how-to-use-cron-in-xampp-windows-step-by-step-to-be-followed-to-use-in-developm

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend looking into Cygwin. I was using that when I wanted linux/unix utilities on Windows. It supports Cron as well.

Jacob

Answer (score 2):

Btw this is a really good question...there are a lot of good scheduled task apps out there. The 1 I liked is Visual Cron at http://www.visualcron.com/

Running a scheduled task, is a very tough thing for web server/web apps to do...Because they have to check every x seconds or minutes to see if a task needs to be done, which can suck up cpu cycles for your web server/apps.

Which is why i prefer using an os based task scheduler or os task scheduling software, better performance I believe.

One trick that I had learned, was using php's -f command to create scheduled tasks without having to open a browser window, then it can run tasks...

On window's systems the only other way was opening up ie/firefox/opera whatever to run your web-based task..

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a windows scheduled task to run cron.php (or call it in the browser).

Comment: on my production server, I wouldn't actually configure the cron itself through drupal, right? I can choose what goes on in cron.php, but the cron job itself has to be done through the server's interface. (cpanel, in my case.) So I could use cron online and windows scheduled task for dev, and they would act essentially the same?