# How to use CRON in xampp windows? Step by step to be followed to use in development

Tags: php, cron

What are the steps to be taken in `xampp[codeigniter]` to use cron and how to make the cron to call our function in `XAMPP Windows`? Do we need to download any exe to run this cron?

> 1. create a batch file to run your php script using php executable "C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\wamp\www\index.php"
> 2. add this batch file in Scheduled Task in Windows control panel.

how to create a batch file thats the code to be written inside batch file?

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231539/run-a-php-script-as-a-background-process-in-wamp-server/4231634#4231634

Comment: @ImranNaqvi 1.create a batch file to run your php script using php executable "C:\wamp\php\php.exe C:\wamp\www\index.php"
add this batch file in Scheduled Task in Windows control panel.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894804/use-php-to-set-cron-jobs-in-windows/22772792#22772792