# Can I use Cron (for scheduling in Codeigniter) in Windows?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to schedule a task in MVC Codeigniter, I would like to know if I can use Cron (for scheduling in Codeigniter) in Windows or it needs to be just Linux??!! Do I need to install any libraries for this purpose?

Any help is appreciated! And if my questions is not clear please let me know which part you need more clarification.

Thanks

Comment: Is the server environment where you are going to publish your site is Linux or Windows? if Linux CRON is the answer, if windows use task manager.

Comment: Thanks! It is a Windows server! In task manager can I say set the path variable like: "C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\application\controllers\task" to call a controller method?

Comment: Notice that "task" is controller method!

Comment: See my answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894804/use-php-to-set-cron-jobs-in-windows/22772792#22772792][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894804/use-php-to-set-cron-jobs-in-windows/22772792#22772792

Answer (score 3):

Cron is a linux thing.  If you are looking to schedule tasks in Windows, please refer to the folllowing: [Scheduling Tasks in Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task)

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
Also I found a better article for Windows task scheduler which is :http://amitdhamu.com/blog/automating-php-using-task-scheduler/  
But my another problem is how can I pass a controller method instead of a a whole web form in this approach! I'm uisng PHP CI

Comment: please don't tag unrelated questions onto existing questions - create a new thread. This is a repository of information for everyone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894804/use-php-to-set-cron-jobs-in-windows/22772792#22772792