# windows xampp cron php script

Tags: php, windows, xampp, scheduled-tasks

Hello I need to run cron every one minute, I made file cron.php and I run cron over CMD. But doesn't work, is this code ok?

```
schtasks /create /tn "organizer" /tr "D:\xampp\php\php.exe\ D:\xampp\htdocs\organizer\cron.php" /ru Administrator /sc minute /mo 1
```

Comment: Would that not be easier to do using the GUI TaskScheduler

Comment: Which one? I need to solve it by CMD :-/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use php to set cron jobs in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894804/use-php-to-set-cron-jobs-in-windows)

Comment: What error are you getting???

Comment: Without erros, just says to me cron has been added. But php script do nothink. PHP script is ok

Comment: If you look at the GUI TaskSceduler Does the task exist there. You can also tell when it was last run etc

Comment: Also try removing the odd trailing backslash so `/tr` looks like this `/tr "D:\xampp\php\php.exe D:\xampp\htdocs\organizer\cron.php"`

Comment: doesn't work, seems like bad options for php.exe