# crontab command not found in my git-bash for windows 7

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5.1, git-bash

I cannot use `crontab -e` in my git that I installed it in my pc windows 7. It produced the error

> bash: crontab: command not found

Did someone use to do it, please tell me?

Answer (score 2):

I confirm that even the [latest git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (2.6.3) with its 4.3.42(3)-bash does not include any cron command.

You would need to use [another "cron from Windows"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron), like the official Microsoft command [`Schtasks.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I am trying to follow your advices

Comment: Do you know how to install and config it in windows 7?

Comment: @SRENGKhorn Are you talking about `Schtasks.exe`? Because it is available for Windows 7: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/schtasks.php, http://blog.mindfall.net/?p=327.

Comment: @SRENGKhorn As for the latest gtit for Windows, there is no setyp: just unzip https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want, and add `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit\usr\bin` to your `%PATH%`: you are good to go.

Comment: So after install and add to `%PATH%` I can use `crontab -e` command in my git-bash?

Comment: @SRENGKhorn my answer is: there is no crontab on Windows: use Schtasks.exe. That what "You would need to use another cron from Windows" means: schtasks as an alternative.

Comment: how to install schtasks in my pc and run it?

Comment: @SRENGKhorn it is already there. It is installed with Windows 7. `C:\WINDOWS\system32\schtasks.exe`

Comment: So How can I set schedule for my command in my Laravel project? any tutorial

Comment: @SRENGKhorn Sure: https://www.appnovation.com/blog/how-set-scheduled-tasks-windows-server-2008. Or the end of the question of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9894804/6309 (which references http://stackoverflow.com/a/9895045/6309)

Comment: I know  how to  set schedule on windows 7 but my problem is how I implement in `.bat` file to execute code in command folder in Laravel. Could u tell me in more details?

Comment: @SRENGKhorn that I don't know as I don't know Laravel well enough and don't know the commands you need to do. That seems basic scripting: `cd /laravel/path`, then your commands.

Comment: @SRENGKhorn Remeber, I am answer your *original* question about scheduler on Windows, nothing more here.