# crontab -e command won't work using Git Bash

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I'm trying to add a schedule in my Laravel using `crontab -e` in my Git Bash but it won't enter me to the crontab configuration where I need to add following Cron entry to my server.

[image: SC]

It works when I fired the command once `php artisan isApprove:update`. Any help why I can't configure this?

**UPDATE**

```
$ echo $PATH
/c/Users/JohnFrancis/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/JohnFrancis/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/xampp/php:/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin:/cmd:/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/c/Users/JohnFrancis/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Comment: From what you have shown, it seems crontab is not installed on your server

Comment: isn't crontab basically installed on every linux system? i'd rather guess that the bash doesn't find the command. what's the output of `which crontab`?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann What do you mean by the output of which crontab?

Comment: @Francisunoxx You type `which crontab` to the shell, show the output that it produces. This is an elementary Unix command.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that your `$PATH` is not set correctly.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I'm just new using this.

Comment: `which` is a command that takes another command name as argument and tells you where it is located on your filesystem. so just type `which command` in your bash, press enter, and show us the output

Comment: @Barmar How can I check If my `$PATH` is not set correctly?

Comment: `echo $PATH` to see what it contains. Make sure it contains both `/bin` and `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @Barmar I updated my post please see the PATH.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I updated my post please see the PATH.

Comment: there we have your problem. you're using a windows-machine. crontab is a unix-command. it's not available on windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [crontab command not found in my git-bash for windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775581/crontab-command-not-found-in-my-git-bash-for-windows-7)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Yes I'm using windows machine. I just installed Homestead on my Laravel.

Comment: gitbash does not include crontab.