# How can I execute PHP in the background of my server?

Tags: php, xampp

I'm new to server-side programming and running a server in general, and I'm using xampp. I have a `hellp.php` file in the `htdocs` directory of xampp, and that's how I run my PHP code. However what I'm looking for, is to have some PHP code execute in the background of my server (not on a webpage). I'm looking for a sort of php application that just runs in the background and does stuff whenever the server starts up.

For example, in this case I want to retrieve some data from Facebook's Graph (a list of conversations from a facebook page) every X seconds and store it in a SQL database somewhere. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: CRON can execute PHP files for items like this. Look up how to create a cronjob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Linux

If you're on linux, you can create a cron job as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22358929/8089090) by @IliaRostovtsev.

## Windows

If you're on windows, use scheduled tasks as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9895045/8089090) by @Pierre.